# How to place the page number of the header in the margin?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using the following code and cannot figure out how to justify the header to the left on the left page and the right on the right page and put the page number in the margin instead of within the defined geometry.

```
\makeatletter
\def\chapapp2{Chapter}

\def\appendix{\par
 \setcounter{chapter}{0}
 \setcounter{section}{0}
 \def\chapapp2{Appendix}
 \def\@chapapp{Appendix}
 \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}

\def\ps@uheadings{\let\@mkboth\markboth
% modifications
\def\@oddhead{\protect\makebox[\textwidth][l]
        {\small\scshape\MakeUppercase{\rightmark}\hfill\thepage}}
\def\@oddfoot{}
\def\@evenfoot{}
\def\@evenhead{\protect\makebox[\textwidth][l]
        {\thepage\hfill\small\scshape\MakeUppercase{\leftmark}}}
% end of modifications
\def\chaptermark##1{\markboth {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
 \chapapp2\ \thechapter. \ \fi ##1}{}}%
\def\sectionmark##1{\markright {\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
   \thesection. \ \fi ##1}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Without [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) I would just suggest to use package [`fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or [`scrlayer-scrpage`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlayer-scrpage) or maybe the interface of the used class or already used page style package.

Comment: Welcome. // Just wondering: where did you get the code from?

Comment: The uhead.sty was created by Ted Shapin, Dec. 17, 1986. I got the code from an overleaf Thesis template. I've edited the code to remove the underline and changed the fonts. 
It seems that fancyhdr is more customisable, so I'll give it a go and see how that goes. Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @katsucurry, thanls for explaining. That was my guess: older code from someboedy else. `fancyhdr` is a good route to go. If you need more flexibility, glance over the various chapters of documentclass `memoir` and pick what you need: https://ftp.mpi-inf.mpg.de/pub/tex/mirror/ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf (and check this site).